# CORS Error when send to request to gateway but it works when I send it to Microservice

Tags: javascript, java, spring-boot, cors, fetch-api

I am building an app using react and spring boot. I have a gateway and a BFF and trying to direct request gateway to bff. While trying to direct POST requests through gateway I get 403 error. Here is the gateway application.properties:

```
    eureka.client.service-url.defaultZone=http://eureka:password@localhost:8761/eureka
spring.application.name=api-gateway
spring.main.web-application-type=reactive

logging.level.root=INFO
logging.level.org.springframework.cloud.gateway.route.RouteDefinitionLocator=INFO
logging.level.org.springframework.cloud.gateway=TRACE

spring.cloud.gateway.discovery.locator.enabled=true
spring.cloud.gateway.discovery.locator.lower-case-service-id=true

## BFF Service Route
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[0].id=bff
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[0].uri=http://localhost:8085
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[0].predicates[0]=Path=/**
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[0].predicates[1]=Method=GET,POST,DELETE, OPTIONS

## Order Service Route
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[1].id=order
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[1].uri=lb://order
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[1].predicates[0]=Path=/**


## Discovery Server Route
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[2].id=discovery-service
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[2].uri=http://localhost:8761
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[2].predicates[0]=Path=/eureka/web
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[2].filters[0]=SetPath=/

##Discovery Server Static Resources Route
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[3].id=discovery-service-static
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[3].uri=http://localhost:8761
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[3].predicates[0]=Path=/eureka/**

spring.security.oauth2.resourceserver.jwt.issuer-uri=http://localhost:8181/realms/spring-boot-microsevices-realm
```

CorsConfig I have in gateway:

```
package com.mealkit.gateway.config;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.CorsRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurer;

@Configuration
public class CorsConfig {

    @Bean
    public WebMvcConfigurer corsConfigurer() {
        return new WebMvcConfigurer() {
            @Override
            public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
                registry.addMapping("/**")  // All endpoints in the application
                        .allowedOrigins("http://localhost:3000")  // Or other origins
                        .allowedMethods("GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE", "HEAD", "OPTIONS")
                        .allowedHeaders("*")// Or other HTTP methods
                        .allowCredentials(true);
            }
        }; }}
```

Controller of bff (btw it works when I directly send the request to bff)

```
package com.mealkit.bff.web.product;


import com.mealkit.bff.api.model.product.request.ProductApiInput;
import com.mealkit.bff.api.model.product.response.ProductApiOutput;
import com.mealkit.bff.api.service.product.product.ProductService;
import lombok.RequiredArgsConstructor;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

import java.util.List;

@RestController
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@RequestMapping("/api/product")
@CrossOrigin(value = "http://localhost:3000")
public class ProductWebApi {

    private final ProductService productService;
    @GetMapping("/getProductById/{productId}")
    public ResponseEntity<ProductApiOutput> getProductById(@PathVariable Long productId) throws Exception {
        return productService.getProductById(productId);
    }

    @PostMapping(value = "/getProductsById")
    public ResponseEntity<List<ProductApiOutput>> getProductsById(@RequestBody List<Long> productIdList) {
        return productService.getProductsById(productIdList);
    }

    @PostMapping("/getProductsByTag")
    public ResponseEntity<List<ProductApiOutput>> getProductByTag(@RequestBody List<Long> tagIdList) {
        return productService.getProductByTag(tagIdList);
    }

    @DeleteMapping("/deleteProduct/{productId}")
    public ResponseEntity<Void> deleteProduct(@PathVariable Long productId) {
        productService.deleteProduct(productId);
        return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.OK);
    }

    @PutMapping("/updateProduct")
    public ResponseEntity<Void> updateProduct(@RequestBody ProductApiInput productApiInput) {
        productService.updateProduct(productApiInput);
        return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.OK);
    }

    @PostMapping("/createProduct")
    public ResponseEntity<Void> createProduct(@RequestBody ProductApiInput productApiInput) {
        productService.createProduct(productApiInput);
        return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.OK);
    }
}
```

here is the code I manage the request on frontend:

```
const URL = "http://localhost:";
const PORT = "8080";
const ORDER_PORT = "8080";
const ORDER_ENDPOINT = "/api/v1/order";
const PRODUCT_ENDPOINT = "/api/product";
const TAG_ENDPOINT = "/api/tag";
const BUSINESS_ENDPOINT = "/api/business";

export const getProductById = async (productId) => {
  try {
    const response = await fetch(
      `${URL}${PORT}${PRODUCT_ENDPOINT}/getProductById/${productId}`
    );
    const data = await response.json();
    return data;
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error:", error);
    throw error;
  }
};

export const getProductsByTag = async (tags) => {
  try {
    const response = await fetch(
      `${URL}${PORT}${PRODUCT_ENDPOINT}/getProductsByTag`,
      {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(tags),
      }
    );
    const data = await response.json();
    return data;
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error:", error);
    throw error;
  }
};

export const getProductsById = async (productIdList) => {
  try {
    const response = await fetch(
      `${URL}${PORT}${PRODUCT_ENDPOINT}/getProductsById`,
      {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(productIdList),
      }
    );
    const data = await response.json();
    return data;
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error:", error);
    throw error;
  }
};

export const getTagsByIds = async (tagIdList) => {
  try {
    const response = await fetch(`${TAG_ENDPOINT}/getTagsByIds`, {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      },
      body: JSON.stringify(tagIdList),
    });
    const data = await response.json();
    return data;
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error:", error);
    throw error;
  }
};

export const getTagById = async (tagId) => {
  try {
    const response = await fetch(
      `${TAG_ENDPOINT}/getTagById/${tagId}`
    );
    const data = await response.json();
    return data;
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error:", error);
    throw error;
  }
};

export const getTags = async () => {
  try {
    const response = await fetch(`${URL}${PORT}${TAG_ENDPOINT}/getTags`);
    const data = await response.json();
    return data;
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error:", error);
    throw error;
  }
};

export const businessGetProductById = async (productId) => {
  try {
    const response = await fetch(
      `${URL}${PORT}${BUSINESS_ENDPOINT}/getProductById/${productId}`
    );
    const data = await response.json();
    return data;
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error:", error);
    throw error;
  }
};
export const placeOrder = async (products) => {
  try {
    const response = await fetch(
      `${URL}${ORDER_PORT}${ORDER_ENDPOINT}`,
      {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(products),
      }
    );
    const data = await response.json();
    return data;
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error:", error);
    throw error;
  }
};
```

Comment: @Override
    public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
        //https://www.baeldung.com/spring-cors
        registry.addMapping("/**")
             .allowedOrigins("*")
             .allowedMethods("GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE", "OPTIONS", "PATCH")
             .allowedHeaders("*")
             //.allowCredentials(true)
             .maxAge(3600);
    }
}

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code for your gateway. For me it is working, and one thing to advice no need cors config for each microservice, because if you are using gateway it will be the only one service which should keep connection with front end other microservices should be closed from outside requests:

```
    @Configuration
    public class CorsConfig {

    private final ConfigConstants constants;

  public CorsConfig(ConfigConstants constants) {
    this.constants = constants;
  }

  @Bean
  public FilterRegistrationBean<CorsFilter> customCorsFilter() {
    UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
    CorsConfiguration config = new CorsConfiguration();
    config.setAllowCredentials(true);
    config.addAllowedOrigin(constants.getAllowedUrl());
    config.addAllowedHeader(constants.getAllowedHeaders());
    config.setAllowedMethods(constants.getAllowedMethods());
    source.registerCorsConfiguration(constants.getAllowedPattern(), config);
    FilterRegistrationBean<CorsFilter> bean = new FilterRegistrationBean<>(new CorsFilter(source));
    bean.setOrder(HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE);
    return bean;
  }
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).